# Checking if an environment variable is empty in C

Tags: c, unix

I have to check if an environment variable exists and if it is an integer value. I have this code:

```
char *aux;
aux=getenv("MAX_OUTPUT");
if (aux==NULL || !(isInteger(aux))){
/*code*/
}
```

I detect when it's not defined with aux==NULL and if it's not an integer with a function I've defined (isInteger). That works, the problem is when the variable exists but is set to the empty string. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `isInteger()` a requirement, or can you use the C function `isdigit(aux[0])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of `isInteger` should be defined (or explicitly undefined) for any inputs. It's not unreasonable to leave the behavior of `isInteger(NULL)` undefined, requiring the caller to  pass a valid string pointer.

As unwind's answer suggests, `isInteger` should probably return false (0) for an empty string.

But if you want to check for an empty string yourself, you can check for a length of 0:

```
char *aux;
aux=getenv("MAX_OUTPUT");
if (aux==NULL || strlen(aux) == 0 || !(isInteger(aux))){
/*code*/
}
```

Or, equivalently, you can check whether the first (0th) character of the string is the terminating null `'\0'` character:

```
char *aux;
aux=getenv("MAX_OUTPUT");
if (aux==NULL || *aux == '\0' || !(isInteger(aux))){
/*code*/
}
```

`*aux` can also be written as `aux[0]`.

Note that this doesn't check for, for example, `aux` containing a single blank: `" "`, but again, `isInteger` should probably handle that.

Assuming that `isInteger` behaves reasonably, returning a true result for any string that looks like an integer and a false result for any string that doesn't (and perhaps with undefined behavior for a null pointer or a pointer that doesn't point to a valid string), then this:

```
if (aux == NULL || !isInteger(aux)) {
    /* it's not an integer */
}
```

should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If `isInteger()` doesn't say `false` for an empty string, I would hesitate to claim that it works. Of course, without the code for `isInteger()` included, it's hard to be more specific.

I think a function like `bool isInteger(const char *str)` must return `false` for both `NULL` and an empty string, so the `aux == NULL` test should not even be needed.

Comment: The standard library functions that deal with strings have undefined behavior if you give them a null pointer. Checking for that case is reasonable, but it's also reasonable to rely on the caller to pass a valid string pointer. In any case, the behavior of `isInteger` needs to be clearly documented.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (aux == NULL || (!isInteger(aux) || !*aux)) {
```

Like that ? *aux test if the string is empty

Answer (score 0):

If after verifying `aux` is not NULL, can you not use the C function `isdigit()` to check the first element of `aux`?

```
if(isdigit(aux[0]){...}
```

or:

```
char *aux;
aux=getenv("MAX_OUTPUT");
if (aux!=NULL)
{
    if(!isdigit(aux[0]))
    {
        /*code*/
    }
}
```

(assuming you are not required to use `isInteger()` )

Comment: What exactly are you treating as an"integer"? Can it start with `'+'` or `'-'`?

Comment: @Keith - I think I see your point.  I would have to expand my answer to handle those possibilities, i.e. +12, or -10?